# PThreads in C, how are thread-IDs generated, why they alternate

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I'm trying to create (3) threads using pthread_create(), and print the thread number and ID in order, for (5) iterations.

Forgive my code, I'm fairly new to C, but I am seeing a strange pattern when my thread creations are printed. For example, my desired output is:

```
Iteration: 1 of 5

        Thread 1 (ID: 140671542023744)
        Thread 2 (ID: 140671533631040)
        Thread 3 (ID: 140671525238336)

Iteration: 2 of 5

        Thread 1 (ID: 140671542023744)
        Thread 2 (ID: 140671533631040)
        Thread 3 (ID: 140671525238336)

Iteration: 3 of 5

        Thread 1 (ID: 140671542023744)
        Thread 2 (ID: 140671533631040)
        Thread 3 (ID: 140671525238336)

Iteration: 4 of 5

        Thread 1 (ID: 140671542023744)
        Thread 2 (ID: 140671533631040)
        Thread 3 (ID: 140671525238336)

Iteration: 5 of 5

        Thread 1 (ID: 140671542023744)
        Thread 2 (ID: 140671533631040)
        Thread 3 (ID: 140671525238336)
```

My actual output is:

```
Iteration: 1 of 5

        Thread 1 (ID: 140671542023744)
        Thread 2 (ID: 140671533631040)
        Thread 3 (ID: 140671525238336)

Iteration: 2 of 5

        Thread 1 (ID: 140671525238336) <-- Order starts reversing here for some reason
        Thread 2 (ID: 140671533631040)
        Thread 3 (ID: 140671542023744)

Iteration: 3 of 5

        Thread 1 (ID: 140671542023744)
        Thread 2 (ID: 140671533631040)
        Thread 3 (ID: 140671525238336)

Iteration: 4 of 5

        Thread 1 (ID: 140671525238336)
        Thread 2 (ID: 140671533631040)
        Thread 3 (ID: 140671542023744)

Iteration: 5 of 5

        Thread 1 (ID: 140671542023744)
        Thread 2 (ID: 140671533631040)
        Thread 3 (ID: 140671525238336)
```

And advice would be greatly appreciated. It's driving me insane. My code is posted below:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

pthread_t threads[3];
pthread_mutex_t mutex;

void * printThread(void * arg) {
  pthread_t id = pthread_self(); // Get pthread ID
  
  printf("\t\tThread %d (ID: %ld)\n", arg + 1, id); // Print thread creation and ID, account for zero index
  
  return NULL;
}

int main(void) {
  int i, j;
  int error;
  
  if (pthread_mutex_init( & mutex, NULL) != 0) {
    printf("\n Error: pthread_mutex_init failure. [%s]\n", strerror(error));
    return 1;
  } // Catch and print pthread_mutex_init error

  printf("Begin multithreading...\n");

  /* Create and print (3) threads by ID, for (5) iterations */
  for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    printf("\t\nIteration: %d of 5\n\n", i + 1);
    for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
      error = pthread_create( & (threads[j]), NULL, & printThread, (void * ) j); // Create new thread
      if (error != 0)
        printf("\nError: pthread_create failure. [%s]\n", strerror(error));
      sleep(2);
    } // Catch and print pthread_create error
    /* Syncrhonize threads */
    pthread_join(threads[0], NULL);
    pthread_join(threads[1], NULL);
    pthread_join(threads[2], NULL);
  }

  printf("\nMultithreading complete.\n");

  /* Cleanup threads and mutex */
  pthread_exit( & threads);
  pthread_mutex_destroy( & mutex);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: According to your understanding, which part of your code do you think is enforcing the ordering that you want? I can't see any code that does that. You just create the threads and let them run in any order that the OS decides. Furthermore, the thread ids are also under the OS control and your expectation of the values seems unrealistic as they may not be the same across pthread_create calls.

Comment: I was only able to synchronize the thread numbers by including sleep(2) within my creation loop, as well as joining the threads inside of my iteration loop. And, I agree with your latter statement, however, I have been tasked with printing these thread creations in such order. From what I've read, I understand the unreliability in order the OS may cause, but I am eager to find a solution. It is the way my code is reversing the order that is perplexing me.

Comment: `sleep` is not a synchronisation mechanism. Never use that for guaranteed synchroisation. And as I said, you don't control the thread ids so you should not be relying on those values at all. If you look at the thread arg values those are already in order. So do you see that the threads are executing in order already (albeit with a fragile sleep mechanism)?

Comment: "*I have been tasked with printing these thread creations in such order*". If this is an assignment I would assume they actually want you to use guaranteed sync mechanisms such as mutexes and semaphores. If you use `sleep` I guess you will be marked down even if the output ends up being "right".

Comment: Yes, I see what you are saying, which is why I am posting this question. The thread number (e.g. 1, 2, and 3) are already in order (synthetically), and used only as a representation of the reiteration of threads. I do seem to have some control over the thread ids, however, the order reverses on every other iteration.

Comment: This is no `synchronisation` question, but you want to know why `thread-ids` flip between iterations.

Comment: "*I do seem to have some control over the thread ids*". Why do you say that? You can see for yourself that you do not. The ids are not "reversing". The OS has its own algorithm for allocating the ids and there is no guarantee that the id values will be the same or in the same order across different pthread_create calls. Your assumption there is not correct and you should not be looking at those ids for ordering. If you think that is what the assignment is requiring then I think you are misunderstanding it (or the assignment is poorly written).

Comment: I say that because the same 3 thread ids are being printed, but in reverse order every other iteration. Forgive me or posing this as a synchronization question, but I am under the assumption that my problem lies with my implementation of thread synchronization. And, yes, the assignment is very poorly written. Regardless, I like to learn things the right way, so I accept your feedback, though I wish my presentation of this question was clearer.

Comment: Then I'm not sure what your question is. There is nothing wrong with the output shown considering how the code has been written. If the question is "how do I get the ids to always be the same" then the answer is "you can't because you can't control what ids the OS will use".

Comment: The ids are the same though, they are simply reversed every other iteration. I'm not asking to control what ids the OS uses, I'm trying to conquer lack of understanding. I can see that we are at an impasse, and I truly appreciate your knowledge on the subject. Could you comment on anything else that stands out in my code as grossly incorrect or poor? I'm honestly very interested in improving.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pthreads is meant to be a very opaque and generic API, so that application code using the pthreads API can be easily ported to as many (often wildly different) platforms as possible.

As part of that philosophy of opacity, the only limitation that pthreads places on the ID values returned by `pthread_create()` is that the ID of each valid (i.e. not-yet-joined) thread be unique with respect to all other valid threads in the process.  Beyond that, all behaviors are left up to the platform's pthreads implementation to handle however it sees fit.

Given that, I don't believe there is any error in the posted code.  The only error is the assumption that the IDs returned by `pthread_create()` should or will follow some additional rules beyond thread-ID-uniqueness -- that is not a valid assumption.

Comment: Thank you, kindly, for your response. I am relieved to know that my assumption was not realistic, and that I am producing the expected output. I will attempt to clarify the expectations for this code, but again, thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 0):

Answered my own question. I was able to circumnavigate the incorrect ordering of my thread creations by printing them from the thread array, as opposed to from a function within my pthread creation.

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int thread;
pthread_t threads[3]; // Initialize thread array
pthread_mutex_t mutex;

void * printThread() {
  pthread_mutex_lock( & mutex); // Lock code

  pthread_t tid = pthread_self(); // Get thread

  printf("\nThread %d (thread-id: %ld) created successfully.", thread + 1,
    tid); // Print thread creation, account for zero index

  pthread_mutex_unlock( & mutex); // Unlock code

  return NULL;
}

int main(void) {
  int iteration;
  int error;

  if (pthread_mutex_init( & mutex, NULL) != 0) {
    printf("\n Error: pthread_mutex_init failure. [%s]\n", strerror(error));
    return 1;
  } // Catch and print pthread_mutex_init error

  printf("Begin multithreading...\n");

  /* Create and print three (3) threads by thread-id */
  for (thread = 0; thread < 3; thread++) {
    error = pthread_create( & (threads[thread]), NULL, & printThread, NULL); // Create new thread
    sleep(1); // Necessary to ensure proper order
    if (error != 0)
      printf("\nError: pthread_create failure. [%s]\n", strerror(error));
  } // Catch and print pthread_create error

  /* Synchronize threads */
  pthread_join(threads[0], NULL);
  pthread_join(threads[1], NULL);
  pthread_join(threads[2], NULL);

  /* Print three (3) threads, in turn, for five (5) iterations */
  for (iteration = 0; iteration < 5; iteration++) {
    printf("\n\n\tIteration: %d of 5 - \n", iteration + 1); // Account for zero index
    for (thread = 0; thread < 3; thread++) {
      printf("\n\t\tThread %d (thread-id: %ld)", thread + 1,
        threads[thread]); // Print threads in turn, account for zero index
      sleep(1); // Sleep to simulate thread step
    }
  }

  printf("\n\nMultithreading complete.\n");

  /* Cleanup mutex and threads */
  pthread_mutex_destroy( & mutex);
  pthread_exit( & threads);

  return 0;
}
```